# What is "it is not the case" in logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am having a doubt in the following question.

Suppose p is the statement 'You need a credit card' and q is the statement 'I have a
nickel.'
Select the correct statement corresponding to the symbols ~(p∨q).
A. You don't need a credit card and I have a nickel.
B. It is not the case that either you need a credit card or I have a nickel.
C. You don't need a credit card or I have a nickel.
D. None of these

Applying De Morgan's laws would lead to this statement: You don't need a credit card and I don't have a nickel, which would make one select option D.
However, in the answer key, it is given option B.
Can someone please explain how to get that answer. Any help is appreciated

Comment: *Either you need a credit card or I have a nickel* translates immediately to $p\lor q$. Prefixing *It is not the case that* to it simply negates it, giving you $\neg(p\lor q)$.

Comment: "It is not the case that..." means "Not"

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott. That was the just explanation I wanted

Comment: @Dev5: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

"You don't need a credit card and I don't have a nickel" translates in symbols as $(\neg p) \wedge (\neg q)$. Note now that you can pull out the negation, since $(\neg p) \wedge (\neg q)$ is logically equivalent to $\neg(p \vee q)$; you can play with truth tables to verify this last claim.

Answer (score 1):

$\lnot(p\lor q)$  would be read as "not $p$ or $q$", or in more fluent English, "neither $p$ nor $q$"

It is hence $B$, neither you need a credit card, nor I need a nickel.